# Which deep learning model to use for sequence completion

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm, autoencoders

I am trying to solve the problem of sequence completion. 
Let's suppose we have ground truth sequence 
(1,2,4,7,6,8,10,12,18,20)

The input to our model is an incomplete sequence. i.e (1,2,4, _ , _ ,_,10,12,18,20). From this incomplete sequence, we want to predict the original sequence (Ground Truth sequence). Which deep learning models can be used to solve this problem?

Is this the problem of encoder decoder lstm architecture?

Note: we have thousands of complete sequences to train and test the model.

Comment: try the BERT model